# как изменить функцию?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как изменить функцию:

```js
function isTrueObject(val) {
  let bool;
  if (val instanceof Array || val === null) {
    bool = false;
  } else if (typeof val === 'object') {
    bool = true;
  } else bool = false;
  return bool;
}

console.log(isTrueObject({ x: 1 }));
console.log(isTrueObject(1));
console.log(isTrueObject(0));
console.log(isTrueObject('jfkjv'));
console.log(isTrueObject(false));
```

что бы был такой вид:

```js
function isTrueObject(val) {
  return expression;
}
```

Comment: по сути instanceof и instanceof возвращает true/false и мне нужно использовать те значения для того что бы узнать передаю я в функцию именно объект или что то другое

Comment: Лучше использовать `Array.isArray`. Текущая проверка с `instanceof` может в определённых случаях глючить.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так

```js
function isTrueObject(val) {
  return val instanceof Array || val === null ? false : typeof val === 'object' ? true : false;
}

console.log(isTrueObject({ x: 1 }));
console.log(isTrueObject(1));
console.log(isTrueObject(0));
console.log(isTrueObject('jfkjv'));
console.log(isTrueObject(false));
```

Comment: по сути это то же что и у меня, только записное через  тернарный оператор

Comment: @Анна ну да, вопрос был как привести код функции к виду **return expression**?

Comment: по сути instanceof и instanceof возвращает true/false и мне нужно использовать те значения для того что бы узнать передаю я в функцию именно объект или что то другое